# How to implement NOT EXISTS in OPEN QUERY statement in PROGRESS 4GL - OpenEdge 10.2A

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to create a browse such that it will show all the records from one table if the values of a field do NOT exist in another table.

It is possible to get the records using SQL as:

```
SELECT myField FROM pub.myTable WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT myField FROM pub.myTable2 WHERE myTable2.myField=myTable.myField)
```

It is also possible using 4GL as:

```
FOR EACH myTable WHERE 
NOT CAN-FIND(FIRST myTable2 WHERE myTable2.myField=myTable.myField)
```

The problem is when I put this query in a browse as:

```
OPEN QUERY myBrowse
FOR EACH myTable WHERE 
NOT CAN-FIND(FIRST myTable2 WHERE myTable2.myField=myTable.myField)
```

it gives an error message

```
CAN-FIND is invalid within an OPEN QUERY. (3541)
```

The question is, is it possible to write such an OPEN QUERY statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't come up with this, Steve Moore shared it on https://community-archive.progress.com/forums/00026/27143.html

```
define temp-table ttNoOrder
       field field1 as char.

create ttNoOrder.

define query q1 for Customer, Order, ttNoOrder.

open query q1 for each Customer no-lock,
     first Order of Customer outer-join no-lock,
     first ttNoOrder where not available(Order).

get first q1.

repeat while not query-off-end("q1"):
   display Customer.CustNum Customer.Name available(Order).
   get next q1.
end.
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I have changed my code using this method. So everything works now. Thanks for your help.
define temp-table ttDummy
       field field1 as char.

create ttDummy.

OPEN QUERY myBrowse
FOR EACH myTable NO-LOCK,
FIRST myTable2 OUTER-JOIN WHERE myTable2.myField=myTable.myFieldNO-LOCK,
FIRST ttDummy WHERE not avail(myTable2).

Answer (score 2):

Works even with dynamic queries:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttNoOrder
       FIELD field1 AS CHARACTER .

DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

CREATE ttNoOrder.

CREATE QUERY hQuery .

hQuery:SET-BUFFERS (BUFFER Customer:HANDLE,
                    BUFFER Order:HANDLE,
                    BUFFER ttNoOrder:HANDLE) .

hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE ("for each Customer no-lock, ~
     first Order of Customer outer-join no-lock, ~
     first ttNoOrder where not available(Order)") .

hQuery:QUERY-OPEN() .
hQuery:GET-FIRST () .

REPEAT WHILE NOT hQuery:QUERY-OFF-END:
   DISPLAY Customer.CustNum FORMAT ">>>>>>>>>9" Customer.Name AVAILABLE(Order).
   hQuery:GET-NEXT ().
END.
```